# The difference of two odd integers x and y is 4. Prove that x and y are relatively prime.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

First I let $x=2n+1, y=2q+1$.

Then $ x-y = 2n+1-(2q+1) = 4 \implies n=2+q$.

I subbed this into $x$ and got $x=2q+5, y=2q+1$.

Then I let

$$d=\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(2q+5,2q+1)$$

$$ \implies d | 2q+5-(2q+1)$$

$$\implies d|4$$

but we want d divides 1.

I also tried $x=2n-1, y=2q-1$ and $x=2n-1, y=2q+1$ but this also led to $d$ divides $4$.

Comment: Please see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about how to display math correctly in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG for $k\gt1$ the value of $\gcd{(2k+5,2k+1)}$ can be given by the Euclidean algorithm as follows
$$2k+5=1\times(2k+1)+4$$
$$2k+1=n\times4+1$$
$$4=4\times1+0$$
or
$$2k+5=1\times(2k+1)+4$$
$$2k+1=m\times4+3$$
$$4=1\times3+1$$
$$3=3\times1+0$$
In either case the value of $\gcd{(2k+5,2k+1)}$ is $1$ hence the numbers are relatively prime. The cases $k=0,1$ can be proved seperately.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: no odd prime divides $4$.

Answer (score 2):

It's the special case $\, a = 2 = k\ $ below.

**Lemma** $ $ If $\,a\,$ is coprime to $\,b\ \&\ c\,$  and $\,b -c = a^k\, $ then $\,(b,c) = 1$

**Proof** $ $ By Euclid $\,(b,c) = (b\!-\!c,c) = (a^k,c) = 1,\,$ by $\,(a,c) = 1\,\Rightarrow\, (a^k,c) = 1$ by inductively applying Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: $(x,a)=1 \land x-y=a^k\implies (y,a)=1$, of course.

Answer (score 0):

$(x,4)=1$.  So by Bezout's theorem,  there are $a,b$ with $4a+xb=1$.  But then $x=y+4\implies (x-y)a+xb=1\implies y(-a)+x(a+b)=1\implies (x,y)=1$.

This generalises to $x-y=c^k$, with $(x,c)=1$.